# How to fix errors when trying to run a server using django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to learn how to use Django and I have created a folder called "lecture3" and when I type in **lecture3 % python manage.py runserver**, I get the error

lecture3 : The term 'lecture3' is not recognized as the
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
lecture3 % python manage.py runserver
~~
CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (lecture3:St
ring) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: You have to change the directory of the terminal/command line to the lecture3 directory, then run python manage.py runserver. You can do that with the cd command on both Windows and Linux

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to execute these commands in your terminal (MacOS, Windows, Linux, all the same):

```
django-admin startproject lecture3
```

1. It will create the folder `lecture3` inside your current folder and populate the folder with a proper minimal data. Perhaps you've already done that.

```
cd lecture3
```

2. This way you will get inside the folder `lecture3`

```
python manage.py runserver
```

3. It will run the server with data from the current folder `lecture3`.